# Using Styled Components with nested styles for React Search Bar, trying to place two different SVGs at opposite sides of the search bar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I have a Search Bar React component that I'm building using Styled Components. I have two separate SVGs I'm trying to add to the inside of the input but on separate sides.

The first SVG is already positioned properly to show up on the left side of the search bar and is just a static SVG.

The second is a Circle X/Close icon that I wrapped in a button in order to pass it a clear input onClick handler and I'm trying to place this icon on the right side of the Search Bar like this:

```
--------------------------
|search              ⓧ |
--------------------------
```

The issue I'm having is that both SVGs and my Input field are all styled as children of a parent `<div>` that passes down nested styles to the corresponding elements, and because of this both icons are overlapping each other on the left side.

Because of this I have no idea how to separate the stylings for both SVGs so that can style them independently.

I have a CodeSandbox here demonstrating the issue:

[image: Edit focused-water-feke2]

And here's my current component with styles:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export const FilterTextbox = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  };
  const clearInput = () => {
    setText('');
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <StyledInput className={"inputWithIcon"}>
        <Input
          type="text"
          value={text}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Search"
          onSubmit={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
          }}
        />
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          width="36px"
          height="36px"
        >
          <path d="M 13.261719 14.867188 L 15.742188 17.347656 C 15.363281 18.070313 15.324219 18.789063 15.722656 19.1875 L 20.25 23.714844 C 20.820313 24.285156 22.0625 23.972656 23.015625 23.015625 C 23.972656 22.058594 24.285156 20.820313 23.714844 20.25 L 19.191406 15.722656 C 18.789063 15.324219 18.070313 15.363281 17.347656 15.738281 L 14.867188 13.261719 Z M 8.5 0 C 3.804688 0 0 3.804688 0 8.5 C 0 13.195313 3.804688 17 8.5 17 C 13.195313 17 17 13.195313 17 8.5 C 17 3.804688 13.195313 0 8.5 0 Z M 8.5 15 C 4.910156 15 2 12.089844 2 8.5 C 2 4.910156 4.910156 2 8.5 2 C 12.089844 2 15 4.910156 15 8.5 C 15 12.089844 12.089844 15 8.5 15 Z" />
        </svg>

        <button onClick={clearInput} style={{ all: 'unset'}}>
          <svg  width="24pt" height="24pt" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1">
            <g id="surface1">
              <path d="M 12 1.546875 C 6.203125 1.546875 1.5 6.25 1.5 12.046875 C 1.5 17.84375 6.203125 22.546875 12 22.546875 C 17.796875 22.546875 22.5 17.84375 22.5 12.046875 C 22.5 6.25 17.796875 1.546875 12 1.546875 Z M 17.078125 15.585938 C 17.148438 15.65625 17.183594 15.75 17.183594 15.847656 C 17.183594 15.945312 17.148438 16.046875 17.078125 16.109375 L 16.0625 17.128906 C 15.988281 17.203125 15.894531 17.234375 15.800781 17.234375 C 15.707031 17.234375 15.609375 17.199219 15.539062 17.128906 L 12 13.585938 L 8.464844 17.132812 C 8.394531 17.207031 8.296875 17.242188 8.203125 17.242188 C 8.109375 17.242188 8.011719 17.203125 7.941406 17.132812 L 6.929688 16.117188 C 6.859375 16.046875 6.820312 15.953125 6.820312 15.851562 C 6.820312 15.753906 6.859375 15.65625 6.929688 15.589844 L 10.476562 12.027344 L 6.917969 8.511719 C 6.773438 8.367188 6.773438 8.128906 6.917969 7.984375 L 7.929688 6.964844 C 8 6.894531 8.09375 6.859375 8.195312 6.859375 C 8.292969 6.859375 8.386719 6.894531 8.457031 6.964844 L 12.003906 10.46875 L 15.554688 6.964844 C 15.625 6.894531 15.71875 6.859375 15.816406 6.859375 C 15.914062 6.859375 16.007812 6.894531 16.078125 6.964844 L 17.089844 7.984375 C 17.234375 8.128906 17.234375 8.367188 17.089844 8.511719 L 13.53125 12.027344 Z M 17.078125 15.585938 "/>
            </g>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </StyledInput>
    </form>
  );
};

const Input = styled.input`
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding-left: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;

  :focus {
    border-color: dodgerBlue;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 dodgerBlue;
  }
`;

const StyledInput = styled.div`
  svg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 8px;
    padding: 9px 8px;
    fill: black;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  input:focus + svg {
    fill: dodgerBlue;
  }

  &.inputWithIcon {
    position: relative;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think of `StyledInput` as the container with having a left icon and button at right side with an icon and style those. IMO, The actual `input` should only focus on itself and the container should determine the style of others ( excluding the focus obviously which is dependent on the input ).
You can do something like this :

https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-shadow-c5wxp

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export const FilterTextbox = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  };
  const clearInput = () => {
    setText("");
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <StyledInput className={"inputWithIcon"}>
        <Input
          type="text"
          value={text}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Search"
          onSubmit={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
          }}
        />
        <div className="left-icon">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            width="36px"
            height="36px"
          >
            <path d="M 13.261719 14.867188 L 15.742188 17.347656 C 15.363281 18.070313 15.324219 18.789063 15.722656 19.1875 L 20.25 23.714844 C 20.820313 24.285156 22.0625 23.972656 23.015625 23.015625 C 23.972656 22.058594 24.285156 20.820313 23.714844 20.25 L 19.191406 15.722656 C 18.789063 15.324219 18.070313 15.363281 17.347656 15.738281 L 14.867188 13.261719 Z M 8.5 0 C 3.804688 0 0 3.804688 0 8.5 C 0 13.195313 3.804688 17 8.5 17 C 13.195313 17 17 13.195313 17 8.5 C 17 3.804688 13.195313 0 8.5 0 Z M 8.5 15 C 4.910156 15 2 12.089844 2 8.5 C 2 4.910156 4.910156 2 8.5 2 C 12.089844 2 15 4.910156 15 8.5 C 15 12.089844 12.089844 15 8.5 15 Z" />
          </svg>
        </div>

        <button className="right-icon" onClick={clearInput}>
          <svg width="24pt" height="24pt" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1">
            <g id="surface1">
              <path d="M 12 1.546875 C 6.203125 1.546875 1.5 6.25 1.5 12.046875 C 1.5 17.84375 6.203125 22.546875 12 22.546875 C 17.796875 22.546875 22.5 17.84375 22.5 12.046875 C 22.5 6.25 17.796875 1.546875 12 1.546875 Z M 17.078125 15.585938 C 17.148438 15.65625 17.183594 15.75 17.183594 15.847656 C 17.183594 15.945312 17.148438 16.046875 17.078125 16.109375 L 16.0625 17.128906 C 15.988281 17.203125 15.894531 17.234375 15.800781 17.234375 C 15.707031 17.234375 15.609375 17.199219 15.539062 17.128906 L 12 13.585938 L 8.464844 17.132812 C 8.394531 17.207031 8.296875 17.242188 8.203125 17.242188 C 8.109375 17.242188 8.011719 17.203125 7.941406 17.132812 L 6.929688 16.117188 C 6.859375 16.046875 6.820312 15.953125 6.820312 15.851562 C 6.820312 15.753906 6.859375 15.65625 6.929688 15.589844 L 10.476562 12.027344 L 6.917969 8.511719 C 6.773438 8.367188 6.773438 8.128906 6.917969 7.984375 L 7.929688 6.964844 C 8 6.894531 8.09375 6.859375 8.195312 6.859375 C 8.292969 6.859375 8.386719 6.894531 8.457031 6.964844 L 12.003906 10.46875 L 15.554688 6.964844 C 15.625 6.894531 15.71875 6.859375 15.816406 6.859375 C 15.914062 6.859375 16.007812 6.894531 16.078125 6.964844 L 17.089844 7.984375 C 17.234375 8.128906 17.234375 8.367188 17.089844 8.511719 L 13.53125 12.027344 Z M 17.078125 15.585938 " />
            </g>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </StyledInput>
    </form>
  );
};

const Input = styled.input`
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding-left: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:focus {
    border-color: dodgerBlue;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 dodgerBlue;
  }

  :focus + .left-icon{
    svg{
      fill: dodgerBlue;
    }
  }

`;

const StyledInput = styled.div`
  &.inputWithIcon {
    position: relative;
  }

  .left-icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    svg {
      fill: black;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
  }

  button.right-icon {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    svg {
      fill: black;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
  }
`;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The svg style inside StyledInput style was also affecting the svg inside the button, to fix this prefix the svg style with `& >`

[image: Edit wonderful-torvalds-r9ds0]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export const FilterTextbox = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  };
  const clearInput = () => {
    setText("");
  };
  return (
    <form>
      <StyledInput className={"inputWithIcon"}>
        <Input
          type="text"
          value={text}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Search"
          onSubmit={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
          }}
        />
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          width="36px"
          height="36px"
        >
          <path d="M 13.261719 14.867188 L 15.742188 17.347656 C 15.363281 18.070313 15.324219 18.789063 15.722656 19.1875 L 20.25 23.714844 C 20.820313 24.285156 22.0625 23.972656 23.015625 23.015625 C 23.972656 22.058594 24.285156 20.820313 23.714844 20.25 L 19.191406 15.722656 C 18.789063 15.324219 18.070313 15.363281 17.347656 15.738281 L 14.867188 13.261719 Z M 8.5 0 C 3.804688 0 0 3.804688 0 8.5 C 0 13.195313 3.804688 17 8.5 17 C 13.195313 17 17 13.195313 17 8.5 C 17 3.804688 13.195313 0 8.5 0 Z M 8.5 15 C 4.910156 15 2 12.089844 2 8.5 C 2 4.910156 4.910156 2 8.5 2 C 12.089844 2 15 4.910156 15 8.5 C 15 12.089844 12.089844 15 8.5 15 Z" />
        </svg>
        <button onClick={clearInput}>
          <svg width="24pt" height="24pt" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1">
            <g id="surface1">
              <path d="M 12 1.546875 C 6.203125 1.546875 1.5 6.25 1.5 12.046875 C 1.5 17.84375 6.203125 22.546875 12 22.546875 C 17.796875 22.546875 22.5 17.84375 22.5 12.046875 C 22.5 6.25 17.796875 1.546875 12 1.546875 Z M 17.078125 15.585938 C 17.148438 15.65625 17.183594 15.75 17.183594 15.847656 C 17.183594 15.945312 17.148438 16.046875 17.078125 16.109375 L 16.0625 17.128906 C 15.988281 17.203125 15.894531 17.234375 15.800781 17.234375 C 15.707031 17.234375 15.609375 17.199219 15.539062 17.128906 L 12 13.585938 L 8.464844 17.132812 C 8.394531 17.207031 8.296875 17.242188 8.203125 17.242188 C 8.109375 17.242188 8.011719 17.203125 7.941406 17.132812 L 6.929688 16.117188 C 6.859375 16.046875 6.820312 15.953125 6.820312 15.851562 C 6.820312 15.753906 6.859375 15.65625 6.929688 15.589844 L 10.476562 12.027344 L 6.917969 8.511719 C 6.773438 8.367188 6.773438 8.128906 6.917969 7.984375 L 7.929688 6.964844 C 8 6.894531 8.09375 6.859375 8.195312 6.859375 C 8.292969 6.859375 8.386719 6.894531 8.457031 6.964844 L 12.003906 10.46875 L 15.554688 6.964844 C 15.625 6.894531 15.71875 6.859375 15.816406 6.859375 C 15.914062 6.859375 16.007812 6.894531 16.078125 6.964844 L 17.089844 7.984375 C 17.234375 8.128906 17.234375 8.367188 17.089844 8.511719 L 13.53125 12.027344 Z M 17.078125 15.585938 " />
            </g>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </StyledInput>
    </form>
  );
};

const Input = styled.input`
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding-left: 50px;

  :focus {
    border-color: dodgerBlue;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 dodgerBlue;
  }
`;

const StyledInput = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  & > svg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 8px;
    padding: 9px 8px;
    fill: black;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  input:focus + svg {
    fill: dodgerBlue;
  }
  button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 8px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    top: 16px;
    border: none;
  }

  &.inputWithIcon {
    position: relative;
  }
`;
```